# c++) My calculator code runs but it doesn't do simple questions like 5+10?

Tags: c++, xcode, case, calculator, operation

**please help a newbie out. My code is a simple calculator code; it's supposed to handle +,-,/,* operations. On hindsight, the code does run, but it doesn't do what it's supposed to do. If you input a question, it doesn't give an answer. For instance, if I input 5+10, it has to give 15 as an answer, but it doesn't do that. I've been reviewing my code but I just really don't know what's wrong with it.

```
#ifndef H112
#define H112 020215L
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include<list>
#include <forward_list>
#include<vector>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <regex>
#include<random>
#include<stdexcept>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#if __GNUC__ && __GNUC__ < 5
inline std:: ios_base& defaultfloat(std:: ios_base& b)
{
    b.setf(std:: ios_base::fmtflags(0), std:: ios_base::floatfield);
    return b;
}
#endif

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using Unicode = long;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using namespace std;

template<class T> string to_string(const T& t)
{
    ostringstream os;
    os << t;
    return os.str();
}

struct Range_error : out_of_range {    // enhanced vector range error reporting
    int index;
    Range_error(int i) :out_of_range("Range error: "+to_string(i)), index(i) { }
};


// trivially range-checked vector (no iterator checking):
template< class T> struct Vector : public std::vector<T> {
    using size_type = typename std::vector<T>::size_type;

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    // microsoft doesn't yet support C++11 inheriting constructors
    Vector() { }
    explicit Vector(size_type n) :std::vector<T>(n) {}
    Vector(size_type n, const T& v) :std::vector<T>(n,v) {}
    template <class I>
    Vector(I first, I last) : std::vector<T>(first, last) {}
    Vector(initializer_list<T> list) : std::vector<T>(list) {}
#else
    using std::vector<T>::vector;    // inheriting constructor
#endif

    T& operator[](unsigned int i) // rather than return at(i);
    {
        if (i<0||this->size()<=i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::vector<T>::operator[](i);
    }
    const T& operator[](unsigned int i) const
    {
        if (i<0||this->size()<=i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::vector<T>::operator[](i);
    }
};

// disgusting macro hack to get a range checked vector:
#define vector Vector

// trivially range-checked string (no iterator checking):
struct String : std::string {
    using size_type = std::string::size_type;
//    using string::string;

    char& operator[](unsigned int i) // rather than return at(i);
    {
        if (i<0||size()<=i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::string::operator[](i);
    }

    const char& operator[](unsigned int i) const
    {
        if (i<0||size()<=i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::string::operator[](i);
    }
};


namespace std {

    template<> struct hash<String>
    {
        size_t operator()(const String& s) const
        {
            return hash<std::string>()(s);
        }
    };

} // of namespace std


struct Exit : runtime_error {
    Exit(): runtime_error("Exit") {}
};

// error() simply disguises throws:
inline void error(const string& s)
{
    throw runtime_error(s);
}

inline void error(const string& s, const string& s2)
{
    error(s+s2);
}

inline void error(const string& s, int i)
{
    ostringstream os;
    os << s <<": " << i;
    error(os.str());
}


template<class T> char* as_bytes(T& i)    // needed for binary I/O
{
    void* addr = &i;    // get the address of the first byte
                        // of memory used to store the object
    return static_cast<char*>(addr); // treat that memory as bytes
}


inline void keep_window_open()
{
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Please enter a character to exit\n";
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
    return;
}

inline void keep_window_open(string s)
{
    if (s=="") return;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(120,'\n');
    for (;;) {
        cout << "Please enter " << s << " to exit\n";
        string ss;
        while (cin >> ss && ss!=s)
            cout << "Please enter " << s << " to exit\n";
        return;
    }
}



// error function to be used (only) until error() is introduced in Chapter 5:
inline void simple_error(string s)    // write ``error: s and exit program
{
    cerr << "error: " << s << '\n';
    keep_window_open();        // for some Windows environments
    exit(1);
}

// make std::min() and std::max() accessible on systems with antisocial macros:
#undef min
#undef max


// run-time checked narrowing cast (type conversion). See ???.
template<class R, class A> R narrow_cast(const A& a)
{
    R r = R(a);
    if (A(r)!=a) error(string("info loss"));
    return r;
}

// random number generators. See 24.7.

default_random_engine& get_rand()
{
    static default_random_engine ran;
    return ran;
};

void seed_randint(int s) { get_rand().seed(s); }

inline int randint(int min, int max) {  return uniform_int_distribution<>{min, max}(get_rand()); }

inline int randint(int max) { return randint(0, max); }

//inline double sqrt(int x) { return sqrt(double(x)); }    // to match C++0x

// container algorithms. See 21.9.

template<typename C>
using Value_type = typename C::value_type;

template<typename C>
using Iterator = typename C::iterator;

template<typename C>
    // requires Container<C>()
void sort(C& c)
{
    std::sort(c.begin(), c.end());
}

template<typename C, typename Pred>
// requires Container<C>() && Binary_Predicate<Value_type<C>>()
void sort(C& c, Pred p)
{
    std::sort(c.begin(), c.end(), p);
}

template<typename C, typename Val>
    // requires Container<C>() && Equality_comparable<C,Val>()
Iterator<C> find(C& c, Val v)
{
    return std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), v);
}

template<typename C, typename Pred>
// requires Container<C>() && Predicate<Pred,Value_type<C>>()
Iterator<C> find_if(C& c, Pred p)
{
    return std::find_if(c.begin(), c.end(), p);
}

#endif //H112

int main()
{
    cout<< "please enter expression(+,-,*,/):";
    
    int lval=0;
    int rval;
    char op;
    cin>> lval;
    if (!cin) error ("no first operand");
    while (cin>>op)
    {
        cin>>rval;
        if(!cin) error("no 2nd operand");
        switch (op){
            case '+':
                lval += rval;
                break;
            case '-':
                lval-=rval;
                break;
            case '*':
                lval*= rval;
                break;
            case '/':
                lval/=rval;
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"result:"<<lval<<'\n';
                keep_window_open();
                return 0;
        }
    }
    error("bad expression");
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce the code sample? It looks to me like pretty much all the code before main (including most of the includes) is completely useless/irrelevant. *// microsoft doesn't yet support C++11 inheriting constructors* not only that but judging by this comment this is old code? Inheriting ctors have been supported for years.

Comment: to be honest I don't know what code isn't useful and what code is useless. My book uses the code std_lib_facilities.h but I didn't know how to put the .h header in my program so I just copied the codes from https://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h

Comment: Assume you entered 5, and then +, and then 10, think thru the steps of your code, after doing the addition in line `lval += rval;`, you need to print the result right there.  as of now, your code does not print anything, it just goes to next iteration of the loop. start learning coding by writing simple programs.

Comment: if you don't mind, how do I just print the result right there? Also, thanks for the advice. I'm trying out some codes from a beginner's coding book but maybe I'm not ready for it yet.

Comment: Copying code from a book and then panicking is not a practical way to learn C++. You must start by learning the basics of constructing a program, and bit by bit getting familiar with the tools for input, output, looping, branching, controlling variables, calling functions, working with strings, dealing with memory, _etc_. But most importantly, spending time reading and debugging your own code either via invasive techniques (outputting values) or learning to use a debugger. Learn to probe your program's behavior by figuring out what it does when you give different input.

Comment: In terms of approaching the program right now, first start by asking youself: 1) where do I output the result currently, if at all? 2) under what conditions will that code be reached? 3) can I construct some input that will cause _any_ result (even the wrong one) to be output? 4) when the output is missing or not as I expect, which part of the program is executing at that time?

Comment: The input `1+2=0` will output a `3`. Your input loop is structured strangely, and the result is only printed if it encounters another `op` and another `rval`.

Comment: I will try to learn the basics again. However, I really want to debug this code first. I did review this code over and over again myself. I'm in need of advice in terms of the code itself, not my study method. Thanks for the advice, will study better.

Comment: Nobody is stopping you from debugging this program. We encourage it. The issue is that there is no indication you have done any debugging at all. _Reviewing_ is different, and typically done by more proficient programmers who can determine what a program will do without executing it. For debugging, you should at least take steps to examine your program's flow and the state of your variables for a specific input. Super basic example of debugging: https://godbolt.org/z/fsvaYr5sK

Comment: thanks. I will check that out and try to debug this.

Comment: You should never add to the `std` namespace, and `inline` does not mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 0):

I change your while expression in the main function to this and it works:

```
while (cin>>op)
{
    cin>>rval;
    if(!cin) error("no 2nd operand");
    switch (op){
        case '+':
            lval += rval;
            break;
        case '-':
            lval-=rval;
            break;
        case '*':
            lval*= rval;
            break;
        case '/':
            lval/=rval;
            break;
        default:
            error("operator not supported");
    }
    cout<<"result:"<<lval<<'\n';
    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```